# Do Easter Beers exist?

Tags: specialty-beers, holidays

We all know that Christmas Beers exist  as can be seen in this article: [25 Beers of Christmas](http://twentyfivebeersofchristmas.tumblr.com/). By a Christmas beer, most interpret this to be a seasonal beer.

As such I would like to know if there are any seasonal Easter Beers that exist for [Eastertide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide), especially any national ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are definitely [Easter-themed beers](https://www.pinterest.com/TavernTrove/historic-easter-themed-holiday-beer-stuff/). Though, no official beer-style when it comes to the holiday, it seems... (Barring all "hoppy" puns) Everything goes; from Pilsner to Porter.

[The best beers to enjoy with your Easter egg - The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/food-and-drink/beer/the-best-beers-to-enjoy-with-your-easter-egg/)

[Top 5 Easter Beers - KegWorks](https://www.kegworks.com/blog/top-5-easter-beers/)

[The Easter Beer Festival](http://www.easterbeerfestival.com/) also showcases ciders and perries; the Spring season seems to call for lighter and fruitier beers as opposed to the heavier,  darker beers of the Autumn season, imho.

And, the rabbit/bunny is a main-stay theme with micro-breweries:

[image: Beaster Bunny]

[image: Hoppy Bunny]

[image: Multibunny]

[image: Shuttle Bunny]

[image: Hunny Bunny]

[image: Hot Bun]

[image: Bad Bunny]

Comment: I like the 'Hot cross bunny' - and also the pic of the 'Bad bynny'!  Hope you have all had a good easter.

Answer (score 5):

Here goes a more traditional way at looking at this question! And yes, I do enjoy [Tim Burnett - Bassist's answer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/6775/5064) very much. To each his own.

For those of you who desire more traditional named beers for Easter, here is a small sampling that are available at various places around the globe.

Let us start with the Season with these:

> **The Bruery Saison De Lente**
>
> With mint green bunnies spinning in a vortex around a pink and green Easter egg in the middle of the label, this beer is a thematically perfect addition to the Blog About Beer basket.
>
> **Granville Island Chocolate Imperial Stout**
>
> No Easter basket would be complete without a little chocolate…well maybe some big chocolate. How about 8.4% ABV chocolate?
>
> **Alameda Brewing Bad Bunny**
>
> A whopping 8.2% ABV Imperial Cream Ale, this beer has large quantities of Pilsner malt and candy sugar. With honey and sweet malts on the nose, there are also strong notes of fruit. The higher ABV makes itself known on the back end meaning this bunny got back for sure! This beer has a medium, creamy mouth feel and enough sweetness to let imbibers know it belongs in an Easter basket. - [3 Easter Beers That Will Have You HOPping!](http://blogaboutbeer.com/easter-beer/)

[image: 3 Easter Beers That Will Have You HOPping!]

> **St-Feuillien Påskeøl (Easter Beer)**
>
> Also known as [St-Feuillien Cuvée de Pâques](https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/st-feuillien-paskeol-easter-beer/23172/)
>
> The brewer markets this same or near-same product by more than one names. This can be the result of a brewer distributing this beer under different names in different countries, or the brewer simply changing the name, but not the recipe at different points in time.

[image: St-Feuillien Påskeøl (Easter Beer)]

> Het Anker Brewery brews a very special dark beer every year for Easter called **Gouden Carolus Easter**. This unique beer contains several types of malt and two different kinds of herbs to give it a very fine and well-rounded taste. It boasts a ruby red color and an impressive ten percent alcohol volume. This truly unique beer is a real delight, even for the most critical connoisseur. For ideal tasting, Het Anker recommends serving Gouden Carolus Easter cool and pouring it out gently in one swift movement. Gouden Carolus Easter is scheduled to be released in the U.S. on March 15th of this year. Wetten Importers is excited to offer this unique and special holiday ale. - [Special Easter Beer Release from Het Anker](https://wettenimporters.com/news-events/special-easter-beer-release-het-anker/)

[image: Gouden Carolus Easter]

In Norway, you can find a special beer at Easter – **Paskelbrygg**.

> **[Paskelbrygg](http://www.womansday.com/food-recipes/food-drinks/a2441/traditional-easter-eats-around-the-world-117631/)**
>
> Breweries in Norway began making this special blend of "the best local beers" in 1934, but it met a lot of opposition from Christian groups. After World War II, however, the tradition picked up popularity and is still a common holiday brew today. Photo: Shutterstock.

[image: Paskelbrygg]

And by the way do not forget your **Easter Beer Hunt**!

> [The Islamorada Beer Company](http://www.allthingstreasurecoast.com/event/easter-beer-hunt/133556) is "hiding over 100 beers for their customers to find! First come First served. Beer Hunts will be held every 30 Minutes! Each person will have 10 minutes to find and keep all hidden Beers."

Answer (score 3):

There are a few Easter beers in Germany. In 2017 these beers were available:

[Hasen-Bräu Oster-Festbier](http://www.hasen-braeu.de/bier/oster-festbier)

[Kaiserhöfer Osterbier](http://kaiserhofbraeu.de/biersorten/osterbier/)

[Weltenburger Oster-Festbier](https://www.weltenburger.de/weltenburger-oster-festbier-die-festtagsspezialitaet-zu-ostern/)

This list is a) not full, b) changes every year because not every brewery brews its Easter beer every year.